# Using very large arrays in fortran (gfortran)

Tags: io, segmentation-fault, fortran, gfortran

I'm working with very large arrays, so at first when I try to compile I get an warning due to stack size.

Warning is:

```
    4 | integer, dimension(n,5) :: temp1 
 1 Warning: Array ‘temp1’ at (1) is larger than limit set by ‘-fmax-stack-var-size=’, moved from stack to static storage.
 This makes the procedure unsafe when called recursively, or concurrently from multiple threads.
 Consider using ‘-frecursive’, or increase the ‘-fmax-stack-var-size=’ limit, or c – ...
```

---

That's the code (It may have small mistakes, but I don't think that's the problem, because when I use with small arrays it runs correctly):

```
program fecha
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: n = 100000
    integer, dimension(n,5) :: temp1
    real, dimension(n) :: temp2

    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: dia, mes, ano, hora, minuto
    real, dimension(:), allocatable :: abs1
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    integer :: i = 1
    integer :: iounit, ierr
    character*50 :: formato = '(i2,1x,i2,1x,i4,1x,i2,1x,i2,1x,f7.4)'

    allocate(dia(n), mes(n), ano(n), hora(n), minuto(n))
    allocate(abs1(n))
    dia = 0; mes = 0; ano = 0; hora = 0; minuto = 0; abs1 = 0.0
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    open (newunit = iounit, file = 'datos_elegidos.txt')
    read(iounit,*)

    do
        read(unit = iounit, fmt = formato, iostat = ierr) temp1(i,1), temp1(i,2), temp1(i,3), temp1(i,4), temp1(i,5), temp2(i)
        if (ierr /= 0) exit
        write(*,*) temp1(i,1), temp1(i,2), temp1(i,3), temp1(i,4), temp1(i,5), temp2(i)
        i = i + 1 
    end do
    i = i-1    
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    deallocate(dia, mes, ano, hora, minuto, abs1)
    allocate(dia(i), mes(i), ano(i), hora(i), minuto(i), abs1(i))

    dia(:i) = temp1(:i,1)
    mes(:i) = temp1(:i,2)
    ano(:i) = temp1(:i,3)
    hora(:i) = temp1(:i,4)
    minuto(:i) = temp1(:i,5)
    abs1(:i) = temp2(:i)

    !print*, dia
    close(iounit)

end program
```

This is part of the txt:

```
dia mes ano hora min abs370 

 3  6 2016  0  5  30.4570   
 3  6 2016  0 10  27.5388   
 3  6 2016  0 15  23.1983   
 3  6 2016  0 20  22.3339   
 3  6 2016  0 25  22.0864   
 3  6 2016  0 30  20.9339   
 3  6 2016  0 35  21.8094   
 3  6 2016  0 40  21.3255   
 3  6 2016  0 45  22.1972   
 3  6 2016  0 50  21.2331   
 3  6 2016  0 55  21.6099   
 3  6 2016  1  0  20.4057
```

Comment: I do not see any particularly large array in your code. Also, you do not "attach" a .txt here, you copy and paste the content. At least a part of it.

Comment: @VladimirF How do I attach a txt here? I'm a begginner here

Comment: See [ask] then.

Comment: @VladimirF. Thanks, I edit it.

Comment: Does the file really contain those empty lines?

Comment: If I read your numbers in a loop (with `rewind`) it works even for `n=10000000` without any special flags. Please make sure it is really this code that is problematic. Tell us the details about your OS.

Comment: @VladimirF I edit it.

Comment: @VladimirF . It's Windows 10. The code works for a small amount of data in a txt, but it doesn't when I use a large amount of data.

Comment: Which compiler edition? MinGW? WSL? Which version exactly?

Comment: @VladimirF. Cygwin (last updated). I just test it with this warnings and a large amount of data (at first I didn't dare), without any flags, and it's works correctly (I think so). But is there any form to correct this warnings?

Comment: Which warnings?

Comment: @VladimirF. This one:     4 |     integer, dimension(n,5) :: temp1
      |                                    1
Warning: Array ‘temp1’ at (1) is larger than limit set by ‘-fmax-stack-var-size=’, moved from stack to static storage. This makes the procedure unsafe when called recursively, or concurrently from multiple threads. Consider using ‘-frecursive’, or increase the ‘-fmax-stack-var-size=’ limit, or c

Comment: I see, you have to mention those warnings in your question. However, those warnings does not matter at all. But if you want to ask about them, please rewrite your question so that it is about that warning.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR;: Just ignore or silence the warning, it is pointless**

This warning comes as a new feature of gfortran 10. I find it to be just noise. You do not have any single Fortran procedure in your code. Therefore,  there is no risk of running your procedures recursively and no need to do anything to your stack (using `ulimit` or nay other tool).

Basically it says that the arrays were placed into the static storage. That is a fixed part of memory. But it is completely fine! There is nothing wrong with static storage for main program data or module data or common block data or similar.

Placing the data in the static storage makes the data effectively `save`. But main program data is `save` automatically by the Fortran standard.

I consider this warning for a main program to be a compiler defect. Accordingly, I have submitted a bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98411  (I checked for duplicates first, before reporting, but didn't find any.)